# C program to use Unix System call for I/O

Tags: c, unix

My professor asked me to write a simple C program, then asked me to convert using Unix system calls.  I have try changing the values around but nothing is working.

Requirement: 
Write a new C program newcat, which performs exactly as oldcat,   but   uses   the following UNIX   system   calls   for I/O.

```
int read(int fd, char *buf, int n);
int write(int fd, char *buf, int n);
int open(char *name, int accessmode, int permission);
int close(int fd);
```

To open a file for read, you can use the symbolic constant O_RDONLY   defined   in   fcntl.h header file to specify the accessmode.  Simply pass 0 for permission. That is, the code will appear as follows:

```
fd = open (filename, O_RDONLY, 0);
```

You will need the following header files:  sys/types.h, unistd.h and fcntl.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* oldcat: Concatenate files */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   void filecopy(FILE *, FILE *); /* prototype for function */
   int fd = open(*fp, O_RDONLy,0)
   char *prog = argv[0]; /* program name for errors */
   if (argc == 1) /* no args; copy standard input */
      filecopy(0, 1);
  else 
      while (--argc > 0)
         if (fd == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: can't open %s\n", prog, *argv);
            return(-1);
         } else {
            filecopy(fp, 1);
            fclose(fp);
     }
  return(0);
}
/* filecopy: copy file ifp to ofp */
void filecopy(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp)
{
   int c;
   while ((c = getc(ifp)) != EOF)
      putc(c, ofp);
}
```

Is this the write idea?  It still won't compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* oldcat: Concatenate files */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   void filecopy(int ifp, int ifo); 

   int fd = open(*File,O_RDONLY,0);  //is this correct?
   char *prog = argv[0]; 
   if (argc == 1) /* no args; copy standard input */
      filecopy(0, 1); //is this correct?
  else 
      while (--argc > 0)
         if ((fd == -1)  //is this correct?{
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: can't open %s\n", prog, *argv); 
            return(-1);
         } else {
            filecopy(*FILE, 1);//is this correct?
            close(*FILE);//is this correct?
     }
  return(0);
}
/* filecopy: copy file ifp to ofp */
void filecopy(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp)//NO CLUE HOW THIS SHOULD BE
{
   int c;
   while (c = read(fd ,&something,1)//What is &ch/&something?
      putc(c, ofp);
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: This does not contain a question.

Comment: Look up the return values.  Hint: `open()` returns an `int`, not a pointer.  And most (but not all) system calls return -1 on error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about asking what your professor means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `oldcat` uses the C standard library calls (like `fopen`), it's a simple matter of mapping those to the UNIX calls.

At a high level:

```
fopen  -> open
fread  -> read
fwrite -> write
fclose -> close
```

For example, when opening your input file with:

```
FILE *fIn = fopen ("jargon.txt", "r");
```

you could instead use:

```
int inFd = open ("jargon.txt", O_RDONLY, 0);
```

The other calls are very similar, with similar functionality at the C standard library and UNIX system call levels. Details on those calls can usually be obtained from the manpages by entering something like `man 2 open` into your shell, or by plugging `man open` into your favourite search engine.

The only "tricky" mapping is if you've used `getchar/putchar`-style calls to do the actual reading and writing but that too becomes easy when you realise that (for example) reading a character is functionally identical to reading a block of size one:

```
int c = getc (fIn);
```

or:

```
char c;
int numread = read (inFd, &c, 1);
```

---

For your added question:

> So to open a file: if (fd = open (fp, O_RDONLY, 0); ) == NULL)

Not quite. The `fopen` function returns NULL on error because it returns a pointer to a `FILE` structure.

The lower level calls use file *descriptors* rather than file handles, the former being a small integer value. So, instead of:

```
FILE *fp = fopen ("nosuchfile", "r");
if (fp == NULL) doSomethingIntelligent();
```

you would do something like:

```
int fd = open ("nosuchfile", O_RDONLY, 0);
if (fd == -1) doSomethingIntelligentUsing (errno);
```

---

In terms of what you need to change, the following comes off the top of my head (so may not be *totally* exhaustive but should be a very good start):

- Add the required headers.
- Stop using `FILE*` totally, using `int` instead.
- Translate the `fopen/fclose` calls to `open/close`. This includes the function name, different parameters *and* different return types.
- Modify `filecopy` to use file descriptors rather than file handles.
- use `1` instead of `stdout` when calling `filecopy` (the latter is a `FILE *`).

---

As an example of how to do this, the following program `testprog.c` will read itself and echo each character to standard output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main (void) {
    int num, ch, inFd;

    // Open as read only.

    inFd = open ("testprog.c", O_RDONLY, 0);
    if (inFd == -1)
        printf ("\n**Error %d opening file\n", errno);

    // Get and output esach char until EOF/error.

    while ((num = read (inFd, &ch, 1) != 0) == 1)
        putchar (ch);

    // Detect error.

    if (num != 0)
        printf ("\n**Error %d reading file\n", errno);

    // Close file and exit.

    close (inFd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank! I believe Im understanding what he wants now.

Comment: Sorry, I cant' get it to open a file.

Comment: void filecopy(FILE *, FILE *); /* prototype for function */
       FILE *fp;
       char *prog = argv[0]; /* program name for errors */
       if (argc == 1) /* no args; copy standard input */
          filecopy(stdin, stdout);'  This is where i need to change to read in a file?

Comment: @Van, I'll add a checklist to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that documentation of `linux sys calls` is present in `manual` called `man pages` which you can access by using `man` command in bash shell in a `linux` system. As UNIX and Linux are quite similar (maybe equivalent) for the syscalls you are interested in you can check the man page for those syscalls in Linux.

All the four `read`, `write`, `open` and `close` linux syscalls are explained in `man pages`. You can access the manual page for these syscalls by typing below commands in shell:

```
man 2 read
man 2 write
man 2 open
man 2 close
```

These should probably guide you to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
/* newcat: Concatenate files */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
   void filecopy(int ifp, int ofp); /* prototype for function */

   int fd;
   char *prog = argv[0]; /* program name for errors */
   if (argc == 1) /* no args; copy standard input */
  filecopy(0,1);
   else 
      while (--argc > 0)
         fd = open(*++argv , O_RDONLY,0);
         if ( fd == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: can't open %s\n", prog, *argv);
            return(-1);
         } else {
            filecopy(fd, 1);
           close(fd);
         }
   return(0);
}
/* filecopy: copy file ifp to ofp */
void filecopy(int ifp, int ofp)
{
   int c;
   while (read(ifp,&c,ofp ) != 0)
      write(ofp,&c,ofp);
}
```

Comment: This is the answer to my question.  How to convert C to unix